# Symfony 3.3 - Doctrine - Doctrine - Persisting with a join table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm developing a website with the PHP framework Symfony 3.3 and the ORM Doctrine.

I have users, and each user can offer services. A service can be offers by more than one user.

Everything is working well, except when I want to persist a services list of a user. Nothing happens and I don't get any error. Can you see anything that is wrong in my code?

My User class (part of it):

```
 class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
 {

     public function __construct(){
        $this->services = new ArrayCollection(); // Services offered by the user
     }

     /**
     *  
     * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $services
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Service", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="service_offer")
     * 
     */

    private $services;

    function getServices() {
        return $this->services;
    }

    function setServices(ArrayCollection $services) {
        $this->services = $services;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

My Service class (part of it):

```
class Service
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_service", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idService;

    /**
    * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $users
    * 
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="services")
    * 
    **/
    private $users;
}
```

In my controller, I have:

```
class ServiceOfferController extends Controller {
/**
 *
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
 * 
 * 
 * @Route("/member/ServiceOffer", name="ServiceOffer")
 */
public function serviceOfferAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em){

    //$user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(ServiceOfferType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()){
        // Services ticked in the formular
        $services = $form->get('services')->getData();

        $user = $this->getUser();

        $user->setServices($services);

        print_r($user->getServices());

        // Persisting in the DB
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('serviceOffer.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

}

"print_r($user->getServices());" returns me data, but nothing is persisting in the table service_offer. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

also tried with specifying the columns, like that:

```
/**
 *  
 * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $services
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Service", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="service_offer",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_service", referencedColumnName="id_service", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *   }
 * )
 * 
 */
private $services;
```

EDIT 2:

My service_offer MySQL table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `service_offer` (
`id_service_offer` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_user` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`id_service` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_service_offer`),
INDEX `fk_service_idx` (`id_service`),
INDEX `fk_user_idx` (`id_user`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_service` FOREIGN KEY (`id_service`) REFERENCES `service` (`id_service`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_user` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify columns parameters for join table.

```
/**
 *  
 * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $services
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Service", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_service",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *   }
 * )
 * 
 */

private $services;
```

Comment: Thank you! Already tried, actually. Just tried now, and still the same problem. Gonna edit my first post with your solution. I'm struggling with this issue for many days already!! I don't really know how to debug, since there is no error... Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't see where do you define $services in function

Comment: I have similar entity relations in my code and it works. Maybe you need to clean entity metadata and update schema again?

Comment: I'm gonna edit my first post and put the whole code I have for the controller. ;)

Comment: Ok, I'll clean entity metadata and update my schema again.

Comment: Hmm, still the same issue. I did: php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata - php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query - php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result - php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug --no-warmup - php bin/console cache:warmup --env=dev

Comment: I did also "php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql" and got this message: Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

Comment: For info, I added the service_offer table description. ;)

Comment: I have the same code for mappings except I didn't use inversedBy attribute. Don't really work with forms. You can check if service is being persisted. Also red somewhere that annotations comments might affect mappings.

Comment: Ok. Took the inversedBy attribute off. Still not working. Had already tried before, actually. ^^

Comment: What do you mean with "annotations comments might affect mappings"? Which comments? "@ManyToMany", etc.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154039/discussion-between-mike-kor-and-rafael-moser).